# How do i insert one value for all rows?

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO vacation_credits
                        (credits)
                            values('15')";
```

i would like to know how to make this one value insert all in the row of data example would be. all i done so far is doing all one by one but would like to know how to make single button that would just insert all rows

Name    Credits
Juan      15
Dela

Comment: Well, INSERT adds a new row, you may be looking for UPDATE if you want to do that for all existing rows in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If the rows already exist, you want to `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE vacation_credits SET credits = 15;
```

(No `WHERE` clause means ALL rows will be updated)

Another option that might work well for you is to set a default value in the table definition:

```
ALTER TABLE vacation_credits
    CHANGE credits credits INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 15;
```

That way, new records will always receive the default value in that column, unless you specify a different one in your insert.

Comment: UPDATE vacation_credits SET credits = 15; by using this code would update all vacation_credits for all exist user or just one ?

Comment: @KalmaKun it would update ALL. To limit which ones get updated, use a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: $update = "UPDATE vacation_credits  SET credits = 15;";
  $qry = mysql_query($update); as i use the code it wont update the database what did i do wrong ?

Comment: @KalmaKun perhaps your MySQL connection params? Also `mysql_query()` is unsafe and deprecated, so make sure you're connecting to your DB in a secure way.